# Font Face is Not appearing

Tags: html, css, fonts, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am using the Skeleton Grid System and I followed the directions commented out in the layout.css file provided in the grid files to change the global font face of my pages. The issue that I am finding is that it is not overwriting the base.css file font face.

Here are the changes I made in the layout.css file:

[image]

And I added the folder "fonts" to the root directory:

[image]

When I run the page locally, the base.css file font appears:

[image]

[image]

Do I need to just overwrite the base.css file?

Comment: I also updated the layout.css file code to make it "../fonts/*FILE*" as per requirement of directing the css file to the fonts folder. located in the root foler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@font-face` simply declares which fonts you want to use. To actually apply web fonts do something like.

```
body {
    font-family: 'HouschaAlt', helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

I assume this definition needs to go in your `base.css` file.

Comment: Thanks. It worked when I applied the font to the base.css file. Do you know how I would be able to style the font like the font files I uploaded? i.e. BlackItalic.ttc or Medium.ttc

Comment: I believe the rendering engine takes care of that for you when you apply say `font-style: italic` to the regular font. However, you can also apply BlackItalic.ttc yourself but you need to declare it as a separate font-face.